# Number of questions is aligned wrong

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

The number of questions is aligned wrong on the newest questions page:
[image]
[image]

Images from Computer Science Educators.SE and Math.SE, respectively.

This happens on Firefox, Safari and Chrome and regardless of whether I'm logged in or not. The problem also exists on Newest '[tag]' Questions and Unanswered Questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has been fixed. Issue with CSS specificity that has been corrected. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, looks fixed! (I wonder, is this the quickest fix ever for a bug reported? Probably not, but it will be close. I can't even accept the answer yet)

Comment: @wythagoras Hehe. I'm not sure. Most likely I noticed the issue while you were writing up the report. I had already pushed a fix to build out in the next prod build.